# OSGeo4W error - The procedure entry point ... NCSEcw.dll

Tags: gdal, ecw, osgeo4w

There are a few posts with a similar error but none with this particular dll. When I try to run a gdal executable from the command line or try to open the OSGeo4W shell I get the following error...

[image]

In the terminal I get the error...

`ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.`

There are no duplicate dlls in the OSGeo4W folder. I have also deleted the OSGeo4W folder and reinstalled. Still get the same error. It also appears that Pathfinder Office has the same dll, but it's in a different directory. The system worked great until a couple of weeks ago with both Pathfinder and OSGeo4W installed. I'm not sure what has changed since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSGEO4W has upgraded to GDAL 1.11, but QGIS 2.2 not; causing the version conflict. The dll should have the same date as the GDAL exe files. I described here how to downgrade the ecw driver:

[How to change GDAL version in QGIS to get ECW import to work](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102193/how-to-change-gdal-version-in-qgis-to-get-ecw-import-to-work)

The GDAL utilities should always be called from within the OSGEO4W Shell, or the SDKShell provided by the gisinternals builds.

If you don't need ECW support, you could simply delete or move the dll.

Comment: Deleting the dll worked. I'm not using any ERDAS data, so no problem there. I would like to comment that I think there must be something I'm doing in the install process. I installed OSGeo4W on a fresh machine yesterday, no Pathfinder or anything really, and I was getting the same error. When I search on the web all I find is this same post. I'm surprised more folks aren't getting this error.

Comment: Did the OSGEO4W ecw driver install by default? I thought it has to be selected manually.

Comment: I'm not sure. There is a check box of recommend installs during the 4W install that I always select. Next time I install it I will check to see if that dll is in that list.

Comment: The `Advanced install` lets you select the packages you want, then adds the necessary depenencies.